# Azure Service Bus Forward Dead Letter Message Forwarding

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a queue setup in Azure Service Bus with a message TTL of 5 seconds(is this too short? I noticed it will stay in the Active status for much longer than 5 seconds).

After it expires I would like it to be forwarded to another queue for processing(timeout queue). I've set the ForwardDeadLetteredMessagesTo property to the timeout queue's name, but when the message expires on the original queue it just goes into that original queues dead letter queue instead of going into the timeout queue.

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to be working?

My use case is I've got some consumers that are only listening on the main queue at certain times of the day. If nothing is listening on the main queue, I'd like it to expire and get pushed to the timeout queue. The timeout queue always has a consumer so it should then pick up that message and process it correctly. I can have multiple main queues, so I'd like to have all the main queues forward their expired messages to the timeout queue so I don't have to have a consumer for each main queue's dead letter queue.

Answer (score 1):

The scenario sounds reasonable. Setting `DefaultMessageTimeToLive` and/or `Message.TimeToLive` with Dead-Letter auto-forwarding is not enough. You actually have to get those expired messages into dead-letter first. For that, you'll need to set [`EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.queuesettings.enabledeadletteringonmessageexpiration.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as well for the scenario to work.

> I noticed it will stay in the Active status for much longer than 5 seconds).

That's normal. For expired messages to be removed from the queue, there's got to be an active listener. Therefore be careful not to overflood your queue if you have many messages that expired and not a single consumer trying to receive non-expired messages.